window is not define when are angular-slickgrid, Angular 18
window is not define in angular 18 version when are using third party library angular-slickgrid
ERROR ReferenceError: window is not defined
at TreeDataService (D:\AngularProject\cloud-hrms.angular\cache\18.2.1\vite\deps_ssr\angular-slickgrid.js:27309:5)
at _AngularSlickgridComponent (D:\AngularProject\cloud-hrms.angular\cache\18.2.1\vite\deps_ssr\angular-slickgrid.js:39234:65)
at NodeInjectorFactory.AngularSlickgridComponent_Factory (D:\AngularProject\cloud-hrms.angular\cache\18.2.1\vite\deps_ssr\angular-slickgrid.js:40137:10)
at getNodeInjectable (D:\AngularProject\cloud-hrms.angular\cache\18.2.1\vite\deps_ssr\chunk-OANVUEAC.js:16479:38)
at instantiateAllDirectives (D:\AngularProject\cloud-hrms.angular\cache\18.2.1\vite\deps_ssr\chunk-OANVUEAC.js:20277:23)
at createDirectivesInstances (D:\AngularProject\cloud-hrms.angular\cache\18.2.1\vite\deps_ssr\chunk-OANVUEAC.js:19876:3)
at ɵɵelementStart (D:\AngularProject\cloud-hrms.angular\cache\18.2.1\vite\deps_ssr\chunk-OANVUEAC.js:27181:5)
at Module.ɵɵelement (D:\AngularProject\cloud-hrms.angular\cache\18.2.1\vite\deps_ssr\chunk-OANVUEAC.js:27225:3)
at AngularSlickgridModule (d:/AngularProject/cloud-hrms/src/app/pages/task-list/task-list.component.html:14:5)
at executeTemplate (D:\AngularProject\cloud-hrms.angular\cache\18.2.1\vite\deps_ssr\chunk-OANVUEAC.js:19848:5)

If you don't need SSR, you should disable it.

@MatthieuRiegler If we use use client, we can get rid of these kind of issues. we create a standalone component, that has AngularSlickGridModule, then we can use it anywhere in the application, without the need for wrapping inside a defer block everytime.

You'll have to be more explicit on what use client is, as this is not a core feature of angular.

@MatthieuRiegler ok I will raise a new feature request with exact use cases and reason, we need this for angular

This has already been asked and declined : https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/57422
